# Combining JSON Values into One Text

Tags: javascript, json

I am using this javascript to display the value of the forecast snow during a 6 hour period onto a HTML.  The text on the HTML shows... 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.35, 0.20, 0.25 instead of 1.55. The JSON results comes back with 6 different forecast snowfall values and I need to add all the values together into one value to be displayed.

JSON's Responds looks like this...

```
{"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"periods":[{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.35},{"snowIN":0.20},{"snowIN":0.25}]}]}
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.aerisapi.com/sdk/js/latest/aerisweather.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    window.onload = () => {

        const target = document.getElementById('data-reading');
        const aeris = new AerisWeather('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');

        const request = aeris.api().endpoint('forecasts').place('pierre,sd').filter('1hr').limit('48');
        request.get().then((result) => {
            const data = result.data;
            const { periods } = data[0];
            if (periods) {
                periods.reverse().forEach(period => {
                    const snowIN = period.snowIN || '0.00';

                    const html = (`
                                 <p class="map-datavalue">${snowIN}"</p>
                            `);

                    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
                });
            }
        }); 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Where are you adding the values ? Your for loop is adding a new html element for every value..

Comment: On the HTML, would like the javascript to add the values obtained from the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the total of your periods with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const target = document.getElementById('data-reading');

const result = {"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"periods":[{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.35},{"snowIN":0.20},{"snowIN":0.25}]}]} 

const data = result.response;
const { periods } = data[0];
if (periods) {
  const total = periods.reduce((sum, { snowIN }) => sum + snowIN, 0);
  const html = `<p class="map-datavalue">${total || '0.00'}</p>`;
  target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
}
```

```css
.map-datavalue { 
  font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: -2px 0 #000000, 0 2px #000000, 2px 0 #000000, 0 -2px #000000;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-datavalue" id="data-reading" style="position: absolute; left: 181px; top: 56px; width:76px; height:30px">&nbsp;</div>
```

Just insert this into your `if (periods) { ... }` like this:

```
request.get().then((result) => {
    const data = result.data;
    const { periods } = data[0];
    if (periods) {
        const total = periods.reduce((sum, { snowIN }) => sum + snowIN, 0);
        const html = `<p class="map-datavalue">${total || '0.00'}</p>`;
        target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
    }
});
```

Regarding this:

```
const total = periods.reduce((sum, { snowIN }) => sum + snowIn, 0);
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < periods.length; ++i) {
    total += periods[i].snowIN;
}
```

but uses destructuring to get the `snowIN` property and uses `reduce` to abstract away the `for` loop.

Comment: Fancier answer ftw

Comment: I am not able to edit the JSON which comes a API subscription.

Comment: You don't need to edit it either, you just have to use it to calculate the sum, as show with reduce here

Comment: I updated the code if (periods) into the html.  Having issues with the Array.reduce.

Comment: What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: I guess I am not sure how to apply
the Array.reduce

Comment: I will add more explanations to clarify this part then.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, is there a way I can show you what I have on the html?

Comment: You could share a link to a jsbin, or a jsfiddle maybe? or edit your question and insert it there

Comment: I have added what I have in a HTML to your answer.

Comment: Ok, yes there was a useless " in the HTML line, I updated it: <p class="map-datavalue">${total || '0.00'}</p>

Comment: Updated, with no results.

Comment: You  didn't close the block for window.onload function

Comment: I updated my snippet with part of your HTML and CSS. The problem is not with reduce, but how you get your data or when you call the logic

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Good question, maybe it would be more appropriate to post that as a separate question though since it is not related to the question here which was about summing the values.

Comment: Thank you for your time and appreciate your patients.

Comment: My pleasure, I hope this answered the summing problem you posted! If so, consider marking answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the values together..

You can keep a var to store the value outisde the for scope and add to it, then just add that element.

```
const request = aeris.api().endpoint('forecasts').place('pierre,sd').filter('1hr').limit('48');
var valueToAddToTML = 0;

request.get().then((result) => {
    const data = result.data;
    const { periods } = data[0];
    if (periods) {
        periods.reverse().forEach(period => {
            const snowIN = period.snowIN || '0.00';
            valueToAddToTML += snowIN;

        });
        // Add to HTML
        const html = (`<p class="map-datavalue">${valueToAddToTML}"</p>`);
        target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
    }
});
```

Comment: 5,17952134 

This did not work. This is the js code I placed into the html. window.onload = () => { const target = document.getElementById('data-reading'); const request = aeris.api().endpoint('forecasts').place('pierre,sd').filter('1hr').limit('48'); var valueToAddToTML = 0; request.get().then((result) => { const data = result.data; const { periods } = data[0]; if (periods) { periods.reverse().forEach(period => { const snowIN = period.snowIN || '0.00'; valueToAddToTML += snowIN; });

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the total sum of `snowIn`, simply use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which gives you a one-liner solution, as stated on `sum`

```
const result = {"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"periods":[{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.35},{"snowIN":0.20},{"snowIN":0.25}]}]}  

const sum = res['response'][0]['periods'].reduce((a, b) =>a + b['snowIN'], 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can club all snowIN into a single value value before adding to html.

```js
let obj = {"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"periods":[{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.25},{"snowIN":0.35},{"snowIN":0.20},{"snowIN":0.25}]}]} 

let op = obj.response[0].periods.reduce((out,{snowIN})=>out+snowIN,0)

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = op
//console.log(op)
```

```css
#text{ color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id='text'>
```